# Generic Service Implementation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, autofac

In my learning ASP.NET MVC 4 application, I use repository pattern and service layers. Entity framework and Autofac is used in the project. My data classes are simple and almost all operations are basic CRUD operations.

I have an abstract repository base as:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> where T : class
```

And this is a sample repository for the entity Sample1:

```
   public class Sample1Repository : RepositoryBase<Sample1>, ISample1Repository
   {
        public Sample1Repository(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
            : base(databaseFactory)
        {
        }
    }

   public interface ISample1Repository : IRepository<Sample1>
   {
   }
```

This is my controller:

```
public class SampleController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISampleService _sampleService;

    public SampleController(ISampleService sampleService)
    {
        this._sampleService = sampleService;
    }
}
```

And, lastly this is my service:

```
public interface ISampleService
{
    IEnumerable<Sample1> GetSample1s();
    Sample1 GetSample1(int id);
    void CreateSample1(Sample1 item);
    void DeleteSample1(int id);
    void SaveSample1();
}

public class SampleService : ISampleService
{
    private readonly ISample1Repository _sample1Repository;

    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public SampleService(ISample1Repository sample1Repository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this._sample1Repository = sample1Repository;
        this._unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
}
```

Now, I have these questions:

1) Do I need to create a separate class for each entity repository. (ie. another Sample2Repository for the entity Sample2)

2) Can I use a generic service for doing those CRUD tasks?

3) If generic service is possible. How can I register it/them in Autofac bootstrapper?

Answer (score 4):

> 1) Do I need to create a separate class for each entity repository.

If you can, create a single generic `IRepository<T>` implementation and map that to this open generic interface.

> 2) Can I use a generic service for doing those CRUD tasks?

Of course you can, but the real question is: is it useful to do so? Seems to me that your `ISampleService` simply duplicates the logic from the `IRepository<T>`. It probably forwards to this repository. Seems like a useless abstraction to me. If your application is truly CRUD, you can inject your repository directly into your controller.

> 3) If generic service is possible. How can I register it/them in
>   Autofac bootstrapper?

You can map an open-generic interface to an open generic implementation as follows:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EntityFrameworkRepository<>))
    .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
```

If you have many concrete (non-generic) `IRepository<T>` implementations and want to batch-register them, you can do this as follows:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IRepository<>).Assembly)
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IRepository<>));
```

Comment: I added 'builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(RepositoryBase<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>));' as you suggested but now it throws an error "Sequence contains no matching element" on 'IContainer container = builder.Build();'

Comment: @SherleyDev: That's not a very descriptive exception message :-(. I have no idea what's wrong. Try updating your answer and add the exact stack trace of this message.